# How to separate 2 TXT files based on ID

Tags: batch-file, csv

I have a .TXT file with several million rows and need to implement a routine that seperates them into two distinct IDS 1 and 2, depending on the first Character within the row. Is it possible to manage it in a .BAT instruction?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. But you need to show your own efforts, otherwise this question is too broad. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the lines based on the first character (`1` or `2`).
Use two `findstr` commands (one for each ID):

```
findstr /b "1" file.txt > file-1.txt
findstr /b "2" file.txt > file-2.txt
```

`/b` means, the line should **b**egin with the search string (`1` or `2`)

Comment: if this doesn't work for you, please show us a few of the problematic lines of your txt file.